# Django: forms how to safe gaurd hidden fields from any malicious user modifying

Tags: django, django-forms

I want my user to login via OTP.

So he will fill the EmailForm and click the button sendotp

forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Please Enter valid Email Address', label='Email address', max_length=254)
```

Then in my views.py i will save the email and generate an OTP and save it and then send OTP using send_email

After that it will open a new template with OTPForm with email as hidden.

views.py

```
form= OTPForm(initial={'email': userfilled_email}
return render (request, 'template2',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class OTPForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    otp = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),help_text='Please Enter valid OTP sent to your Email', label='Otp', max_length=6)
```

I want to have email as hidden. When the form is submitted, i will need the email so that i can verify the otp sent to mail and otp entered by user.

I heard that some malicious user try to modify the hidden field it when you don't want them to.

So what is the best way to save from such situations.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent a user from modifying a hidden input.

Comment: Does the email come from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent a user from modifying input. However, since you put the email into the form in the view, why can't you just verify that the email is the same in the next view? Why can't malicious input be detected that way?

Answer (score 0):

I found my approach of using hidden field i not safe. I found that i can use session to pass the email to my next view.

```
def view1(request):     
     # get email from form and check for form.is_valid():
     email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
     # then
     request.session['email'] = email
     # render ...........

def view2(request):
    if 'email' in request.session:
         email = request.session['email']
```